# What scriptures describe Brahma's son Sanatkumara being reborn as Shiva's son Kartikeya?

Tags: brahma-sutras, adi-shankaracharya, kartikeya, chandogya-upanishad

As I discuss in [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3193/36), by far the most popular school of Hindu philosophy is the Vedanta school, which bases its tenets on the doctrines laid out in the Brahma Sutras, a work by the sage Vyasa that summarizes and systematizes the philosophical teachings of the Upanishads. You can read the Brahma Sutras [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3193/36).  In any case, Adhyaya 3 Pada 3 Sutra 32 of the Brahma Sutras says this:

> Topic-19: People with a Mission
>
> 32. Those who have a mission to fulfill continue in the corporeal state as long as the mission demands it.

All the commentators interpret this Sutra as saying that although in most cases when a person attains knowledge of Brahman they attain Moksha as soon as they die, in a small number of cases they take another birth in order to fulfill some role that is vital to sustaining the Universe.  In Adi Shankaracharya's [commentary](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe38/sbe38175.htm) on this Sutra, he gives some example of people who were born again for a purpose even after attaining knowledge of Brahman:

> The question here is whether for him who has reached true knowledge a new body originates after he has parted with the old one or not.--But an objection is here raised at the outset there is really no occasion for inquiring whether knowledge when reaching its perfection brings about its due effect, viz. complete isolation of the Self from all bodies or not; not any more than there is room for an inquiry whether there is cooked rice or not, after the process of cooking has reached its due termination; or, for an inquiry whether a man is satisfied by eating or not. Not so, we reply. There is indeed room for the inquiry proposed, as we know from itihâsa and purâna that some persons although knowing Brahman yet obtained new bodies. Tradition informs us, e.g. that Apântaratamas, an ancient rishi, and teacher of the Vedas, was, by the order of Vishnu, born on this earth as Krishna Dvaipâyana at the time when the Dvâparayuga was succeeded by the Kaliyuga. Similarly, Vasishtha, the son of Brahman's mind, having parted from his former body in consequence of the curse of Nimi, was, on the order of Brahman, again procreated by Mitra and Varuna. Smriti further relates that Bhrigu and other sons of Brahman's mind were again born at the sacrifice of Varuna. **Sanatkumâra also, who likewise was a son of Brahman's mind, was, in consequence of a boon being granted to Rudra, born again as Skanda.** And there are similar tales about Daksha, Nârada, and others having, for various reasons, assumed new bodies.

In my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/7044/36) I discuss Apantaratamas' rebirth as Vyasa, and in my question [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7979/36) I discuss Vasishta's rebirth as the son of Mitra and Varuna.  But my question is, what scriptures describe Brahma's son Sanatkumara being reborn as Shiva's son Kartikeya, aka Skanda or Muruga?

For those who don't know, Sanatkumara is one of the four Kumaras, the first four mind-born sons of Brahma who are most famous for cursing Jaya and Vijaya as I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2042/36).  In any case, the only reference I know of to a connection between Sanatkumara and Kartikeya is in the Chandogya Upanishad, at the [end of a dialogue](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe01/sbe01160.htm) between Sanatkumara and the sage Narada:

> The venerable Sanatkumâra showed to Nârada after his faults had been rubbed out, the other side of darkness. **They call Sanatkumâra Skanda, yea, Skanda they call him.**

But are there any scriptures which describe the story of how and why Sanatkumara was reborn as Kartikeya?  I'm particularly interested in Adi Shankaracharya's statement that it was done "in consequence of a boon being granted to Rudra".  What was the boon, and who gave it to Shiva?

By the way, it's interesting to note that [this chapter](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/3/chapter-view) of the Srimad Bhagavatam says that the four Kumaras are incarnations of Vishnu.  So that would mean that Kartikeya is an incarnation of Vishnu!  That would certainly put the discredited theories that the Venkateshwara statue is Kartikeya in a whole new light.

Also, [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01068.htm) of the Adi Parvati of the Mahabharata says that Krishna's son Pradyumna is an incarnation of Sanatkumara, which would put Pradyumna's fight with Kartikeya, which is part of the fight between Krishna and Shiva that I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2231/36), in an interesting light.

Comment: "Pradyumna is am incarnation of -" you forgot to write Sanatkumara; btw you know Pradyumna was the avatara of **Kamadeva**. Maybe Vyasa was sleepy so he made a mistake.

Comment: Coming to your question: first reaction, "WHAT?"

Comment: Second reaction: I think I have heard this somewhere can't place it though.

Comment: Plus, the meaning of Sanat-Kumara is everlasting Kumara. Muruga (of the north) is an everlasting Kumara. That must mean something.

Comment: @Surya Thanks, I fixed it.  In any case, there isn't any contradiction here; you can be an incarnation of multiple gods at once.  And Kama is considered to be an incarnation of Vishnu's Vyuha Pradyumna form, and Sanatkumara is also an incarnation of Vishnu.

Comment: @Surya By the way, I expect that just as Ganapatyas say there is an eternal Ganesha and he just took an incarnation as the son of Shiva and Parvati, and Shaivites say there is an eternal Sadashiva who just took an incarnation as Brahma's son Rudras, Kaumaras will probably say that there is an eternal Kartikeya who incarnated once as the son of Brahma, and then again as the son of Shiva.  I wonder whether the Skanda Purana says anywhere that Kartikeya incarnated as Brahma's son Sanatkumara.

Comment: But since it says born again, would it imply that Sanatkumara left his present body to become Kartikeya?

Comment: Also Samba is an incarnation of Kartikeya/Siva. So where does that add up? Additionally Muruga is also Shiva in another form since Surapadman could be defeated only by Shiva.

Comment: @Surya Well, I'm not sure if he left his body, snce after the part I quoted Adi Shankaracharya says "Of some of the persons mentioned it is said that they assumed a new body after the old body had perished; of others that they assumed, through their supernatural powers, various new bodies, while the old body remained intact all the while." Heres the original Sanskrit so you can check whether it says Sanatkumara left his body: भृग्वादीनामपि ब्रह्मण एव मानसपुत्राणां वारुणे यज्ञे पुनरुत्पत्तिः स्मर्यते सनत्कुमारोऽपि ब्रह्मण एव मानसः पुत्रः स्वयं रुद्राय वरप्रदानात् स्कन्दत्वेन प्रादुर्बभूव एवमेव

Comment: @Surya I'm not sure how much stock I put in the details of the Surapadman story, since your question about whether it has a basis in Sanskrit scripture hasn't been answered.  But yeah, the Pradyumna vs. Samba issue is interesting.  Perhaps Pradyumna is a Purna avatara of Sanatkumara, while Samba is an Amsha Avataram insofar as he is one degree removed due to being an incarnation of Muruga.

Comment: The Sanskrit just says like Vasishtha and Bhrgu Sanatkumara 'appeared' as Muruga. And regardless of Sanskrit scriptures I believe the Kandha Puranam because it was based on the **southern recession** of the Skanda Purana.

Comment: @Surya No, we have the Southern recension of the Skanda Purana, and it doesn't contain the stories found in the Kandha Purana.

Comment: Give it to me right now. I have searched all over Google for them.

Comment: @Surya I don't know if it's available online, but there is a two or three volume Sanskrit edition with Tamil translation of the Southern recension by Sengalipuram Anantarama Dikshitar.  (It doesn't translate the whole Purana, just the part containing stories of Muruga.) Since you live in India see if you can find it in bookstores.  By the way, I think the one Kandha Puranam story that is there in the Southern recension of the Skanda Purana is the story of Muruga marrying Valli.

Comment: I don't think I am close to **buying** the book... Anyways, Valli Kalyanam is there? Wow. And regarding Sanatkumara, did you know that the [Narayana Kavacha](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/6/8/17) prays to Sanatkumara for protection from **Kamadeva**? That is like another twist in the tale.

Comment: See [this link](http://creative.sulekha.com/the-previous-avtar-of-lord-muruga-kartikeya_230320_blog) which talks about this Sanatkumara as concept as related by Mahaperiyava. Also see [this Stotra](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Pragya_Vivardhana_Karthikeya_Stotram) where Muruga is referred to as **Sanatkumaro Bhagavan**.

Comment: @Surya I found an actual translation of the Devathin Kural lecture alluded to in your link: http://advaitham.blogspot.com/2007/03/deivathin-kural-series-140.html It seems that Kanchi Mahaperiava had the same doubt that I did while reading Adi Shankaracharya's Brahma Sutra Bhashya.  And he asked a knowledgeable friend of his who referred him to chapter 37 of the Mahatmya Kanda of the Tripura Rahasya.  I couldn't find the Mahatmya Kanda in English, but I found it in Sanskrit: http://gdurl.com/pTmE/download Please tell me if chapter 37 has the story about Sanatkumara and Kartikeya.

Comment: You are in luck, because I don't think there can be a more detailed answer to your question. Plus, **I am** in luck, because Surapadman features in the 37th chapter as well. Should I post it as an answer?

Comment: @Surya Great!  Yeah, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 37th Chapter of the Mahatmya Kanda of the Tripura Rahasya details the story of Sanatkumara incarnating as Kartikeya.

Lord Dattatreya relates the story of Lord Muruga to Parashurama, listening to which Parashurama asks Dattatreya:

> Kathamesha Mahabhagah Skandah Tam Asuresvaram|
>   
> Jitavaan Shivavishnvendra-Durjeyamapi Samyuge|| (37.78)
>   
> "O Lord, how was this greatly fortunate Skanda able to conquer the king of Asuras , who was undefeatable by even Shiva, Vishnu and Indra in battle?"

To which Dattatreya replied that Lord Sanat-kumara, the son of Brahma was ever peaceful and content with himself. He dwelt on the Mountain named Rshabha. Once, Lord Brahma arrived to meet his son, and Sanatkumara related a dream he had seen, of a great battle between the devas and asuras.

> Yuddhamaseet Mahabhimam Asuranam Tatha Amaraih|
>   
> Tatra Sarve Maya Yuddhe Nihataah Balavattaraah|| (37.85)
>   
> Asuraas Tat Kathamidam **Nirhetukam** Abhut Vada|
>
> "O Father, I saw a dream, of a great war between the asuras and the devas. I saw myself slaying all the formidable asuras in the war. I want to know how such a **baseless** thing could happen!"

Lord Brahma replied that in a past life, Sanatkumara had been a Brahmana, who having heard the account of the battle between Devas and Asuras, had vowed to defeat all the asuras and return prosperity to the devas, with the fire as his witness. But he attained his death before he could fulfil his vow, so instead of getting Moksha, he incarnated as Brahma's son Sanatkumara. Brahma also told him that whatever he had seen in the dream would actually take place.

When Sanatkumara asked Brahma how this was possible, Brahma told him that Sanatkumara himself would decide how this would take place, and returned to Brahmaloka.

As Sanatkumara meditated on this statement, Lord Shiva and Devi Parvati passed by his hermitage. Seeing his composed face, Parvati (who had not seen Sanatkumara before as she was newly married) asked Lord Shiva who he was. When Shiva told her about Sanatkumara, she expressed her wish to meet him.

When both Mahadeva and Girija reached the hermitage, Sanatkumara didn't notice them. After waiting for a long time, Mahadeva decided to test Sanatkumara and flew into a rage. He scolded Sanatkumara saying that his conduct did not befit him, the son of Brahma. When Sanatkumara was addressed thus, he opened his eyes and said, "I won't be frightened by your curses, nor will I be excited by your boons. I have conquered both fear and excitement, thus you cannot make me react in any way, either ordinary or extra-ordinary."

When he had replied thus, Mahadeva was pleased and asked him to seek a boon. Sanatkumara laughed and said,

> "Saadhayasva Mahadeva Esha Me Kaankshito Varah|| (37.118)
>   
> Maayavinam Maheshaana Naaham Vepayitum Kshamah|
>   
> Mahavaatair-Ivaakasham Bruhi Te Yadi Vaanchitam||(37.119)
>   
> "O Great Lord, Mahadeva, I cannot be agitated by illusions or illusionists, just like hurricanes cannot disturb the sky. Therefore, I seek this boon that, if **you** have any wish, you may seek it from **me**."

Upon hearing this, Mahadeva said 'Om' and continued,

> Yadi Dasyasi Me Kamam Prateeccha Mama Putrataam|| (37.120)
>   
> "If you shall grant my wish, then become my son!"

Sanatkumara smiled and said, "I shall become your son, but **only yours**, because Parvati Devi hasn't asked this boon of me!"

Parvati immediately argued that since the wife was entitled to half of her husband's fortunes and misfortunes, she also was entitled to being his mother. Sanatkumara consented and said, "When Bhasmasura had sought the boon to turn anyone to ashes, and tired it on Shiva, he had disappeared, hearing about which you had become aggrieved and turned into a forest of reeds. I shall incarnate into **that body** of yours; hence you will be my mother."

So saying, Lord Sanatkumara granted them leave, and was born as their son, in the lake (Poigai in Tamil), in the forest of reeds, Sharavanam. Thus he became Lord Muruga.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!  So does that chapter make clear if Sanatkumara abandoned his old body or just assumed a new body while keeping his old body?  By the way, now you can answer your [Surapadman question](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10720/36).

Comment: Also, this is the only reference I know of in all of Hindu scripture to the word "Bhasmasura", about whom a question was posted [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/388/36).  The Srimad Bhagavatam speaks of Vrikasura, who had a similar story but was tricked by Vishnu in the form or a Brahmachari boy rather than in the form of Mohini.  But too bad the Tripura Rahasya doesn't actually mention Mohini defeating Bhasmasura.

Comment: @Keshav Sanatkumara Incarnates as Muruga. He doesn't take another birth.

Comment: Good info. @KeshavSrinivasan But is Moksha guaranteed for Sanatkumara in his current life (if we assume he hadn't taken a new body as Kartikeya by perishing his old body) as he was about to get Moksha. Obviously, there should be some story for Ganesha too. BTW, with this logic Narayana and Rudra (not Brahman) must also have previous births. Right?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan And what's the story of Surapadman?

Comment: @TheDestroyer Yes, Sanatkumara will get Moksha.  That was the whole point of Adi Shankaracharya mentioning him, to give an example of a person who attained knowledge of Brahman, but who delayed getting Moksha so that he could fulfill some important role vital to sustaining the Universe, and then after that role is finished he will attain Moksha.  See this section of Adi Shankaracharya's Brahma Sutra Bhashya: http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe38/sbe38175.htm

Comment: @TheDestroyer According to the Tamil Kandha Puranam, Surapadman is the brother of Tarakasura, and Muruga defeated him in Thiruchendur, one of the Aaru Padai Veedu or six sacred places of Kartikeya.  Kartikeya spared his life and made him into his peacock Vahana.

Comment: @TheDestroyer No, incarnations of Vishnu need not have previous births, although they do in some cases. Concerning Shiva, Madhvacharya had a theory that goes something like this: in the next Mahakalpa, the current Shiva becomes the next Vayu, the current Vayu becomes the next Brahma, and the current Brahma attains Moksha. (That's his explanation for Hanuman becoming  Brahma, a notion I'm unsure of but a question was posted about it [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7311/36).) But I'm not sure if this has a scriptural basis. Madhvacharya had a strange Vayu-centric Vaishnava worldview.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Personally i don't trust Madhavacharya as it looks for me he comes with his own theories which are difficult to find in scriptures and personally i don't believe him as avatar of Adisesha. Adisesha is a good serpent and see how Patanjali was . I meant Rudra not Shiva. Anyways, i think Trimurti might have previous births.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Yeah, I have similar feelings about Madhvacharya; see my questions [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8680/36), [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10819/36), and [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11229/36) where I discuss his questionable quotations.  In any case, Madhvacharya wasn't an incarnation of Adiseshan; his followers consider him an incarnation of Vayu, not Adiseshan.  (Like I said, he preached a Vayu-centric worldview.) Ramanujacharya, whom I follow, is the one who's considered an incarnation of Adiseshan.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Ok. Got confused. Wiki says [he proclaimed himself as avatar of Wind god](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madhvacharya#Self_proclamation_as_being_avatar_of_Wind_god). No real Avatar proclaims himself. People see their divinity.

Comment: Can Moksha be attained only on/after death?

Comment: Fabulous answer @Surya