# Was Rama Avatar a result of four different curses?

Tags: vishnu, rama, curse, yoga-vashishtha, sanatkumara

The Ramayan tells us that Lord Vishnu incarnated as Rama on the request of the demigods when the three worlds were being tormented by the tyranny of Ravan. But the **[Yog Vasishtha](https://archive.org/stream/YogaVasishtaOfValmikiValmiki/Yoga%20Vasishta%20of%20Valmiki%20-%20Valmiki#page/n47/mode/2up)** adds an interesting detail about the curses which led Vishnu to be born on the earth as Rama:

> 57 Sanatkumara, who was devoid of desires, had been residing at the abode of Brahma, to which Vishnu,
>   the lord of the three worlds, was a visitor from Vaikuntha.
>
> 58 The lord god Vishnu was welcomed by
>   all the inhabitants of the Brahmaloka as well as by Brahma himself, except by Sanatkumara. The god
>   Vishnu addressed Sanatkumara,
>
> 59 “Sanatkumara, it is ignorance that makes you forsake your desires
>   for fear of rebirth, therefore you must be born under the name of Sara-janma to be troubled with
>   desires.”
>
> 60
>   In return, Sanatkumara denounced Vishnu by saying, “Even as all discerning as you are, you shall
>   have to sacrifice your omniscience for some time, and live as an ignorant mortal.”
>
> 61 There was another curse pronounced upon Vishnu by the sage Bhrigu who, seeing his wife killed by
>   Vishnu, became incensed with anger and said, “Vishnu you shall have also to be deprived of your
>   wife.”
>
> 62 Vishnu was again cursed by Vrinda to be deprived of his wife, on account of his beguiling
>   her (in the form of her husband).
>
> 63 Again, when the pregnant wife of Devadatta was killed from fear
>   on seeing the man-lion figure of Vishnu (Narasimha),
>
> 64
>   the leonine Vishnu was denounced by the
>   husband who was sorely afflicted at the loss of his wife.
>
> 65 Thus cursed by **Bhrigu, Sanatkumara, Devadatta and Vrinda,** Vishnu was obliged to be born on this
>   earth in the figure of a human being.

**I am aware of the curses by Bhrigu & Vrinda but not sure about the other two. Does any other scripture mention these two stories?**

Comment: Sarajanma refers to Sanatkumara's birth as Shiva's son Kartikeya.  But the Tripura Rahasya describes his birth as a result of a boon Sanatkumara gave to Shiva, as described in [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11298/36).  But perhaps some other scripture describes it as also being a result of Vishnu's curse.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I think there's some confusion, am asking about Vishnu's birth due to Sanatkumar's curse not the other way round :)

Comment: Yeah I know, I'm just clarifying what "therefore you must be born under the name of Sara-janma" means.  If we could find a scripture where Vishnu curses Sanatkumara, we might find the counter-curse as well.

Comment: Hmmm interesting possibility

Comment: As per Ramcharitmanas, these stories are from different kalpas.. in one kalpa Vrinda curses Vishnu..in another, Sanatkumaras curses Vishnu's dwarpalas Jaya and Vijay..in another Narada curses Vishnu etc. etc...in all kalpas, Ravan is also diff like incarnation of Vishnu' dwarpala or Rudragana's...