# Instances of devotee granting boon to deity

Tags: gods, goddess, bhakti, boon

It is normal and expected that a devotee *receives* boon from deities like Siva, Vishnu etc., But, I came across an incident in Mahabharata, in which Garuda grants boon to Vishnu.

> "And the son of Vinata then met Vishnu on his way along the sky. And
> Narayana was gratified at that act of self-denial on the part of
> Garuda. And that deity, knowing no deterioration, said unto the ranger
> of the skies, 'O, I am inclined to grant thee a boon.' The ranger of
> the skies thereupon said, 'I shall stay above thee.' And he again
> spake unto Narayana these words, 'I shall be immortal and free from
> disease without (drinking) Amrita.' Vishnu said unto the son of
> Vinata, 'Be it so.' **Garuda, receiving those two boons, told Vishnu, 'I
> also shall grant thee a boon; therefore, let the possessor of the six
> attributes ask of me.' Vishnu then asked the mighty Garuda to become
> his carrier**. And he made the bird sit on the flagstaff of his car,
> saying, 'Even thus thou shalt stay above me.' And the ranger of the
> skies, of great speed, saying unto Narayana, 'Be it so,' swiftly
> wended on his way, mocking the wind with his fleetness.
>
> [[Section 33, Astika Parva, Adi Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01034.htm)

I also heard that Sanatkumara grants a boon to Shiva and takes birth as kumara Swamy. Which scripture mentions that?

And are there any such other incidents in scriptures?

Comment: Skanda's incident is mentioned here [What scriptures describe Brahma's son Sanatkumara being reborn as Shiva's son Kartikeya?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11298/3500)

Comment: Madhu & Kaitabha were devotees of Devi and gave Vishnu the boon that they would let him kill them.